# Get specific rows which match condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

[image: dataframe]

My current code is as follows: Outcome is to only show instances where ImageFileName is services.exe and the PPIDName is not wininit.exe. Right now my result shows all other rows which are not matching this condition.

```
services = dfprocs[(dfprocs.ImageFileName.str.lower() == "services.exe") & (dfprocs.PPIDName.str.lower() == "wininit.exe") == False]
if  len(services) == 0:
    print("Services.exe was spawned using known parent")
else:
    print("[!]Suspicious services.exe process found")
    print(services)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the requirement mentioned, this should work.

```
services = dfprocs.loc[(dfprocs.ImageFileName == 'services.exe') & (dfprocs.PPIDName != 'wininit.exe')]
```

Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
services = dfprocs[(dfprocs.ImageFileName.str.lower() == "services.exe") & (dfprocs.PPIDName.str.lower() != "wininit.exe")]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) issue here. The `==` operator (which in normal python code would take precedence over `and`) does not take precedence over the bitwise (or in pandas, element-wise) operator `&`.

You can fix it either by putting parens around `(dfprocs.PPIDName.str.lower() == "wininit.exe") == False` or changing to `(dfprocs.PPIDName.str.lower() != "wininit.exe")`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfprocs = pd.DataFrame({
    "TreeDepth":[0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    "PID":[4,88,404,556,632,768,900],
    "PPID":[0,4,4,548,548,632,632],
    "ImageFileName":["System","Registry","smss.exe","csrss.exe","wininit.exe","services.exe","services.exe"],
    "Offset(V)":['0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080','0xac818d45d080'],
    "Threads":[158,4,2,10,1,7,7],
    "Handles":[np.NaN]*7,
    "SessionID":[np.NaN]*3+[0.0]*4,
    "Wow64":[False]*7,
    "CreateTime":[0]*7,
    "ExitTime":[np.NaN]*7,
    "PPIDName":[np.NaN, "System", "System", np.NaN, np.NaN, "wininit.exe", "wininit.exe"]})
print(dfprocs)
services = dfprocs[(dfprocs.ImageFileName.str.lower() == "services.exe") & ((dfprocs.PPIDName.str.lower() == "wininit.exe") == False)]
if  len(services) == 0:
    print("Services.exe was spawned using known parent")
else:
    print("[!]Suspicious services.exe process found")
    print(services)
```

Output:

```
   TreeDepth  PID  PPID ImageFileName       Offset(V)  Threads  Handles  SessionID  Wow64  CreateTime  ExitTime     PPIDName
0          0    4     0        System  0xac818d45d080      158      NaN        NaN  False           0       NaN          NaN
1          1   88     4      Registry  0xac818d45d080        4      NaN        NaN  False           0       NaN       System
2          1  404     4      smss.exe  0xac818d45d080        2      NaN        NaN  False           0       NaN       System
3          0  556   548     csrss.exe  0xac818d45d080       10      NaN        0.0  False           0       NaN          NaN
4          0  632   548   wininit.exe  0xac818d45d080        1      NaN        0.0  False           0       NaN          NaN
5          1  768   632  services.exe  0xac818d45d080        7      NaN        0.0  False           0       NaN  wininit.exe
6          1  900   632  services.exe  0xac818d45d080        7      NaN        0.0  False           0       NaN  wininit.exe
Services.exe was spawned using known parent
```